# NSRegularExpression search string "*string*"

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

i have a list of string i want search string like *A* mean it is only appearance in middle not first or last.My code here:
When i run all 3 case is true, but only case "う上あ" is true

```html
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSArray *array = @[@"上あう", @"う上あ", @"あう上"];
    NSString *stringNeedToFind = @"*上*";
    for (NSString *string in array) {
        if ([[self regularExpressionFromValue: stringNeedToFind] numberOfMatchesInString:string options: 0 range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length)]) {
            NSLog(@"String containt.");
        }
    }
}

- (NSRegularExpression *) regularExpressionFromValue: (NSString *) value
{
    NSString *pattern = [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString: value];
    pattern = [pattern stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\*" withString: @".*"];
    pattern = [pattern stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\?" withString: @"."];
    pattern = [pattern stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @".*.*.*" withString: @"\\*"];
    pattern = [pattern stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"..." withString: @"\\?\\?\\?"];
    pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"^%@$", pattern];
    return [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options: 0 error: NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the asterisk (*) is used as an operator to check if a character (set) is present 0 or more times. I think you should use the plus character (+), e.g. like this: ^.+上.+$, meaning there should be 1 or more characters at the start and at the end.

Comment: haven't tested it by the way